# How can I copy a document across team sites using SP Designer developed workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a requirement to, via SP Designer developed workflow, copy a document from a document library in a team site to a document library in a different team site.  This workflow would be manually triggered, so there are no conditions.  It's a simple copy function.

I can use the 'copy document' action in SP Designer, but can only choose document libraries in the same team site.  My preference is to do this in SP Designer instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: Please check out this article: "How to move documents using workflow in SharePoint 2013 and Office 365" http://plumsail.blogspot.ru/2014/06/how-to-move-documents-using-workflow-in.html

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Steve - It looks like you're right -- I don't see a no-code solution.  This goes beyond my skillset, but I'm going to ask one of our devs to build it for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely need to create your own custom action in Visual Studio that provides this functionality.

This link provides code for a good starting point:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408817/Workflow-to-copy-a-file-from-one-site-to-another-s